# Proposal for tag: [infinite-output]

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently created the [infinite-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infinite-output) tag for my newest challenge. After a [discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56403345#56403345), there's a bit of disagreement on whether it's needed.

Here are some questions I think the tag would apply to:

- [Shortest code to produce infinite output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/13152/shortest-code-to-produce-infinite-output?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C47.5010) (For obvious reasons)
- [Implement a truth machine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/62732/implement-a-truth-machine) (debatable because it only requires infinite output sometimes)
- [Follow a linked list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/216196/follow-a-linked-list) (the original question I added it to)
- [High throughput Fizz Buzz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/215216/high-throughput-fizz-buzz) (to demonstrate that many applicable questions don't simply include the text `infinite` or `infinite output`)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

### I think this is a useful tag

Here are my reasons for making the tag in the first place:

The purpose of tags is to make it easier to find (or ignore) questions involving a specific topic or type of task. The main argument against the tag that I received was that it wouldn't apply to more than maybe ten questions. I disagree.

There are quite a few questions involving infinite output that don't include `infinite output`, so trying to search for them conventionally won't work. This makes it seem like there are fewer applicable questions than there likely are (including the original question I tagged with it). It also gives the tag a good use, since finding related questions is difficult.

Infinite output is a much more common type of challenge than, say, [box-256](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/box-256), and it's definitely possible that someone could be searching specifically for infinite output challenges. I see no downside to having the tag.

Answer (score 2):

## [infinite-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infinite-output) is too specific

Such a tag would be covered by a more general tag, such as [infinite-runtime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infinite-runtime)* which would imply that answers to tagged challenges shouldn't ever stop running (ignoring minor complications such as the heat death of the universe etc.).

For example, answers to [Loading... Forever](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/101289/loading-forever) arguably do not have an infinite output, yet the question says

> **Your program should be able to run indefinitely**

Similar challenges such as [Implement a Truth-Machine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/62732/implement-a-truth-machine) or [Shortest infinite loop producing no output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/59347/shortest-infinite-loop-producing-no-output) which would be edge cases (or not even covered) by [infinite-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infinite-output) would fall under this tag, and, as far as I can tell, we don't have anything that already superseeds or covers this specific tag.

[This](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22forever%22%20is%3aq%20-%5btips%5d%20closed%3ano) is a (non-perfect) search for all 118 open, non-tips challenges that include the word "forever" in the spec. Obviously not all of these will be covered by this tag, but a substantial number would.

---

* There's been [some discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56405676#56405676) in TNB for what this tag would be called. Feel free to comment suggestions that you think would be better

Comment: Suggested tag name: `indefinite`

Comment: There are some ways to produce infinite output in finite runtime.  This can be done by relying on lazy loading, for example infinite lists in Haskell.

Comment: Maybe just [tag:infinite]...it's very vague, but I can't think of much it applies to other than infinite output or infinite runtime